# How do I use regex to extract pair of values from text into lists?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
string='<final:company name>  abc. </final:company name> <final:number of employees> 143.</final:number of employees> <final: average salary>  medium. </final: average salary>'
```

What I want to extract is all the pattern expression headings and then the values separately within the `< >`. So, I want:     -company name,     -number of employees,    -average salary in one list maybe.
and I want to extract the values separately like: *abc,  143, medium*

When I code as follows:

```
regex='<final:(.*?)</final'
pattern=re.compile(regex)
finding=re.findall(pattern,string)
print(finding)
```

I get   ['company name>  abc. ',  'number of employees> 143.',  ' average salary>  medium. ']
Which is not excatly what I am looking for. How do I code this correctly?

Comment: `regex = '<final: *([a-z ]*?)>'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
regex = r'<final:([^>]*)>\s*([^<\s\.]*)'
```

Your group 1 will contain the tags i.e, company name, number of employees, average salary and group 2 will contain their values i.e, abc, 143, medium.

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/BVcePS/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> pattern=re.compile(regex)
>>> finding=re.findall(pattern,string)
>>> print(finding)
[('company name', 'abc'), ('number of employees', '143'), (' average salary', 'medium')]
```

To make 2 different lists from your `finding`, you can do something like this:

```
>>> tags = map(lambda x: x[0], finding)
>>> values = map(lambda x: x[1], finding)
>>> tags
['company name', 'number of employees', ' average salary']
>>> values
['abc', '143', 'medium']
```

or you can also use `zip` to convert it to two lists:

```
>>> tags, values = map(list, zip(*finding))
>>> tags
['company name', 'number of employees', ' average salary']
>>> values
['abc', '143', 'medium']
```

Comment: thanks! I modified it slightly and it worked perfectly. Useful site regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

To allow whitespaces in the content and strip the whitespaces in the tag names you could do

```
import re

string='<final:company name>  abc. </final:company name> <final:number of employees> 143.</final:number of employees> <final: average salary>  medium. </final: average salary>'

rx = re.compile(r'''
    <final:\s*
    (?P<tag>[^>]+)>
    (?P<content>[^<]+)
    </final:\1>''', re.X)

results = {m.group('tag').strip(): m.group('content').strip() for m in rx.finditer(string)}
print(results)
# {'number of employees': '143.', 'company name': 'abc.', 'average salary': 'medium.'}
```

---

Afterwards, you will be able to access your elements like `results['company name']`.
Generally though this looks like some (invalid ?) `XML` file. If it was valid (and you just had some typos while copying to the question) consider using a real parser instead.

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/30d0MZ/1).